# What is the difference between "razor" and "cshtml" files?

Tags: asp.net, razor

What is the difference between "razor" and "cshtml" files in ASP.NET. Should we use ".razor" file in "razor-components" application instead of ".cshtml"?

Answer (score 46):

It depends on which ASP.NET you mean...

For example, in terms of Blazor:

As of .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4 SDK (3.0.100-preview4-011223) it is noted:

- Rename all _ViewImports.cshtml files to _Imports.razor.
- Rename all remaining .cshtml files to .razor.

So if you are building a Blazor Web App using .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4 and later, you should be using .razor instead of .cshtml.

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-now-in-official-preview/

Comment: very much, I searched for the answer to this question a lot, now I found it

Comment: in the last version, the template of blazor server side, includes both types of extensions! there is a `_Host.cshtml` and also some files having `.razor` extension. Why is that? Aren't those `.cshtml` files supposed to be renamed to have `.razor` extension due to your answer? (thanks in advance for your help)

Comment: So why in .net 6, still we have .cshtml in the starting template?

Comment: The [current stand of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) puts this in perspective aptly. `.cshtml` is a page and `.razor` is a component. Please note that MS template for Blazor Server still use the `.cshtml` file. Thus, I suggest we take the suggestion in blog with a pinch of salt to replace all `.cshtml` with `.razor`!

Answer (score 20):

Since Blazor can execute C# on Client side, now there are 2 places - client and server - where Razor code can be executed. So **client side has extension ".razor"** and **server side - ".cshtml"**

I created a new WebAssemblyHosted application and found that:

- There are 3 projects created in solution: Client, Server, and Shared
- **Client** project has **.razor** files and does not have .cshtml files.
  *This project will be compiled and sent .dll to client side, and then executed by .Net which is integrated in browser*
- **Server** project has **.cshtml** files and does not have .razor files.
  *This code compiled and executed on server, as it was done in old asp*
- Shared project contains common types/classes for both Client and Server.
  *Now (finally) you do not need to declare the model class twice in C# on server and in JS on client as it was before. And of cause you do not need map one to the other.*

Comment: Please use the [current stand of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on how `.cshtml` and `.razor` is interpreted.

Answer (score 13):

Razor is a markup syntax that lets you embed server-based code into web pages using C# and cshtml is the extension of razor file Cshtml = cs (C#) + HTML

> Components are typically implemented in Razor Component files (.razor)
>   using a combination of C# and HTML markup (.cshtml files are used in
>   Blazor apps).

.cshtml and .razor is the same thing 
we use .cshtml file in blazor app and .razor in razor components

Comment: Blazor Apps using .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4 now use the .razor extension.

Comment: Saying ".cshtml and .razor is the same thing" is misleading, here are examples of some directives that only applies to MVC views and Razor Pages (.cshtml) [tag-helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tag-helpers) also [@model directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model)

Answer (score 7):

I might be wrong but `.cshtml` file created when adding a new Razor page is a new html page, and `.razor` file created when adding a new Razor component is a component that will fit into a Razor page.

===Reference===

> Razor is a markup syntax for embedding .NET based code into webpages. The Razor syntax consists of Razor markup, C#, and HTML. Files containing Razor generally have a .cshtml file extension. Razor is also found in Razor component files (.razor).

From: [Microsoft Learn portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

.cshtml files are razorpages or MVC views, they do not contain any C#-written client-side code. If you want to do so, you must use JavaScript.
However, a .razor file, also known as a Razor component, can have C# written in it and run on client's browser.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem a little confusing. For Blazor Server, using the .net core 6 blazor template in VS 2022, if I modify the NavMenu with two new items, one points to a .razor page and one points to a .cshtml page.  The one that points to a razor page will display inside the existing layout, the other one will not.  It will replace everything.  Although the .razor page has to have teh @page directive to allow users to navigate to it.

So, at least for Blazor server, razor pages serve multiple purposes

- Controls that can be used in other pages
- Pages (must have @page directive) that can be navigated to, and will appear in the existing layout.  Basically these are probably just controls

.cshtml

- Pages that might use controls, or be used by controls if the page is a laoyout

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but this seems to be a pretty loose differentiator.

Answer (score 0):

Used in your standard .cshtml files, and implemented like so:

```
<BlazorSample.Components.MyComponent />
```

These new extensions are used for Razor Components.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score -1):

razor helps you embed serverside code like C# code into web pages.
cshtml is just a file extension. razor view engine is used to convert razor pages(.cshtml) to html.

Comment: Google search "difference between razor and cshtml" showed me the text from this answer as a snippet of info but now I see it has been downvoted overall.

Answer (score -1):

Razor is a markup language that allows you to embed C# code in HTML. Razor files have the extension .cshtml. Razor-components is a framework for building reusable UI components in ASP.NET. Razor-components applications use .razor files instead of .cshtml files.

There are a few advantages to using .razor files in razor-components applications. First, .razor files are more concise than .cshtml files. This is because .razor files allow you to use C# code to generate HTML, which can reduce the amount of markup that you need to write. Second, .razor files are more maintainable than .cshtml files. This is because .razor files allow you to use C# code to define the behavior of your components, which can make it easier to understand and debug your code.

However, there are also a few disadvantages to using .razor files in razor-components applications. First, .razor files can be more difficult to learn than .cshtml files. This is because .razor files require you to know both C# and HTML. Second, .razor files can be slower to compile than .cshtml files. This is because .razor files need to be compiled into C# code before they can be executed.

Overall, the decision of whether to use .razor files or .cshtml files in a razor-components application depends on your specific needs. If you are looking for a markup language that is concise, maintainable, and easy to learn, then .razor files are a good option. However, if you are looking for a markup language that is fast and easy to use, then .cshtml files are a better option.